# How do I properly use angular form validiation?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am trying to add form validiation to my project. I have built a simple login form and now I want to check the value of the different input fields before sending them to the server and provice visual feedback to the user in case they are invalid. I tried following the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) but I ran into a few issues

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
<div class="content">
    <section>
        <div class="form-wrapper">
            <h3>Registrieren</h3>
            <form class="form" [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit()">
                <div class="form-item">
                    <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-item">
                    <input formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Addresse" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-item">
                    <input formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Passwort" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-item">
                    <button type="submit">Registrieren</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

And the component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  name: string = '';
  email: string = '';
  password: string = '';
  error: string = '';

  constructor( private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(this.name,[
        Validators.required,
      ]),
      email: new FormControl(this.email,[
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$")
      ]),
      password: new FormControl(this.password, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8)
      ])
    })
  }

  submit(){
    this.auth.tryRegister(this.form.getRawValue())
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        if(res.status == 200){
          this.router.navigate(['/verify'])
        }},
      err => {
        if(err.status == 400){
          this.error = 'Invalid form data'
        }
        else if(err.status == 401){
          this.error = 'email address already in use'
        }
      })
  }
}
```

I want to check if the email address is valid, and if it isn't, I would like to give it the styling of my class .is-invalid which adds a red border around the input tag (if there are any existing angular css classes for this purpose I would be happy to use them, too)

I know this is a very basic and trivial question, I am not really familiar with angular, so if you show me how to do it propely or link me any resources I could use I would really appreciate it.

edit: I now added getters for my properties, but it still does not work. Whenevever I try to check `*ngIf="name.errors?.required"` I get the error "object is possibly null", even though I already use the safe navigation operator ?

Comment: Start with the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to access formControls in the html view you need to make a getter for them in the .ts file:

```
get name() {
    return this.form.get('name');
}
```

and then in the HTML view:

```
<div class="error" *ngIf="name.errors?.required">
    Name is required.
</div>
```

Comment: I added this to my html after writing the getters to see if it would work, and I get an error "Object is possibly 'null'". How can I fix it?